# can i use google forms in android app(WebView) to create quiz and place admob ads in it

Tags: android, admob, adsense

Does it violates admob policies or not ?

i have a plan to create an android app with webview and banner ad the bottom of the screen.
can i create quiz using google forms and embed these forms in my webpage without violating admob policies

Comment: this is a question regarding policies of a 3rd party, which we can't help with

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Which ad code should I put on web apps (app embedding web): AdMob or AdSense?
Please don't use AdSense on apps since it is a clear violation. Also please be sure not to violate the following policies when using AdMob."

i think there is no problem if you don't add adsense ad on web.

i still recommend your detailed research.

https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/10257746?hl=en&msgid=10334315